# Existence of the limit in $\mathcal{D}'$ of $1/x \in [-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

**Question:**

Let be $w(x)=1/x$ and
$$w_\varepsilon(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x},&\quad |x| > \varepsilon\\
0,&\quad |x| \leq \varepsilon\\
\end{cases},
$$ with $\varepsilon >0$.

Show that $\forall \phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}), \exists\; \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+} (w_\varepsilon,\phi) = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus [-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]} \frac{\phi(x)}{x}\; dx =: I_\varepsilon(x)$ and is this limit is finite.

**Solution**:

Let be $[-a,a]=\text{supp}(\phi)$ for an arbitrary $\phi$, and the notice that:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus [-\varepsilon,\varepsilon] \cap \text{supp}(\phi)} \frac{\phi(0)}{x}\;dx = \phi(0) \bigg( \int_{-a}^{-\varepsilon} + \int_a^\varepsilon \bigg) \frac{1}{x}\;dx = 0\; \quad (a)$$ because $\int_{-a}^{-\varepsilon} \frac{dx}{x} \overset{x=-y}{=} \int_\varepsilon^a \frac{dy}{y}$.

We also have that:  $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\phi(x) - \phi(0)}{x} = \phi'(x) \quad (b)$

If from $I_\varepsilon(x)$ we substract $(a)$:
$$ |g_\varepsilon(x)|=\bigg|\int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus [-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]} \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}\; dx \bigg|= \bigg|\int_{-a}^a \chi_\varepsilon(X) \frac{\phi(x) - \phi(0)}{x} \; dx\bigg|$$

And let $|g(x)| = \big|\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}\big| \in \mathcal{L}^1(-a,a)$, then we have that $|g_\varepsilon(x)| < |g(x)|$ because $|g_\varepsilon(x)| = |\chi_\varepsilon(x) g(x)|$.

Then $I_\varepsilon(x)$ is bounded, and from the dominated convergence theorem we can conclude that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} I_\varepsilon(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\phi(x) -\phi(0)}{x}\; dx$.

I'm not sure about a couple of things:

1) It's is sufficient to show $(b)$ to ensure the function behave "well" around $0$ when integrated?

2) Is the proof complete or I'm missing some details?

EDIT:

Corrected $w_\epsilon(x)$ definition.

Corrected $w_\epsilon(x)$ definition, again, confused $<$ with $>$.

Comment: Your definition overlaps

Comment: You can't say that $[-a,a] = \text{supp}(\phi)$ will hold for arbitrary $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: You can however take $a$ so big that $\operatorname{supp}(\phi) \subseteq [-a, a]$.

Comment: Your definition of the distribution is unclear. Did you mean $\omega_\epsilon(x) = \frac{1_{|x| > \epsilon}}{x}$ ? In that case $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \langle \omega_\epsilon, \phi \rangle = \langle pv(\frac{1}{x}), \phi \rangle$ the principal value. Since $1/x$ is odd we can realize it as $\langle pv(\frac{1}{x}), \phi \rangle = \langle \frac{1}{x}, \phi-\phi(0) \varphi \rangle$ where $\varphi(x) = e^{1-1/(1-x^2)} 1_{|x| < 1}$ which is $C^\infty_c$ even and $\varphi(0) = 1$

Comment: @user1952009 I have corrected the definition of $w\epsilon(x)$. I think in you observation you wanted to write $\frac{1_{|x|<\epsilon}}{x}$?

Comment: No. $\frac{1_{|x| < \epsilon}}{x}$ doesn't represent a distribution, but $pv(\frac{1_{|x| < \epsilon}}{x})$ does, and this is what you are showing here. Also if I say $\frac{1}{x}$ is a distribution on $C^\infty_c((0,\infty))$ and $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^*)$ do you see any hint ?

Comment: @user1952009 in my observation I wanted just to be sure that you wrote the $>$ sign in the function by accident. It seems so. For the $PV$, at the point where I'm I have just read about the its definition, so I really have no idea what it is. For your hint, is not $\mathcal{D}((0,\infty))=C_c^\infty((0,\infty))$ and $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^*)=C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^*)$ (with its own convergence)?

Comment: No this is not an accident. The definition **is** $pv(\frac{1}{x}) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{1_{|x| > \epsilon}}{x}$ in the sense of distributions, ie. for $\phi \in C^\infty_c$ : $$\langle pv(\frac{1}{x}), \phi \rangle = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1_{|x| > \epsilon}}{x} \phi(x)dx$$ Your job is to show the limit exists and defines a distribution, of finite order

Comment: As I said $w_\epsilon(x) = \frac{1_{|x| < \epsilon}}{x}$ doesn't correspond to a distribution on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @user1952009 My bad! I clearly confused $<$ with $>$. Even in my definition I stated it wrong. Now it is clear, thanks a lot. I fix it again.

Comment: Your job was and still is to show the limit exists and defines a distribution, of finite order. In particular you need to avoid the $L^1$ norm and replace it by the $\sup$ norm for $\phi$ and its derivatives

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi \in \mathcal D$ be given. Through a Maclaurin expansion of $\phi$ we can write
$\phi(x) = \phi(0) + x \eta(x)$
where $\eta(x)$ is bounded as $x \to 0$.

Now take $\delta>0$.

Since $\eta$ is bounded at $0$ there is $a>0$ such that $\int_{|x|<a} |\eta(x)| \, dx < \delta$.

We clearly have $T_a := \int_{|x|>a} \frac{\phi(x)}{x} \, dx$ finite, so let's look at $\int_{\epsilon<|x|\leq a} \frac{\phi(x)}{x} \, dx$:
$$
\int_{\epsilon<|x|\leq a} \frac{\phi(x)}{x} \, dx
= \int_{\epsilon<|x|\leq a} \frac{\phi(0) + x \eta(x)}{x} \, dx
= \phi(0) \int_{\epsilon<|x|\leq a} \frac{1}{x} \, dx
+ \int_{\epsilon<|x|\leq a} \eta(x) \, dx
$$
Here,
$\int_{\epsilon<|x|\leq a} \frac{1}{x} \, dx = 0$ since we integrate an odd function over a symmetric set.

Thus,
$$
\left| \int_{\epsilon<|x|\leq a} \frac{\phi(x)}{x} \, dx \right|
= \left| \int_{\epsilon<|x|\leq a} \eta(x) \, dx \right|
\leq \int_{\epsilon<|x|\leq a} \left| \eta(x) \right| \, dx
\leq \int_{|x|\leq a} \left| \eta(x) \right| \, dx
< \delta
$$
As this doesn't depend on $\epsilon$ we have
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left| \int_{\epsilon<|x|\leq a} \frac{\phi(x)}{x} \, dx \right| \leq \delta$$
so
$$
\left| \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{\phi(x)}{x} \, dx - T_a \right|
= \left| \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{\phi(x)}{x} \, dx - \int_{|x|>a} \frac{\phi(x)}{x} \, dx \right| \\
= \left| \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon<|x|<a} \frac{\phi(x)}{x} \, dx \right|
\leq \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left| \int_{\epsilon<|x|<a} \frac{\phi(x)}{x} \, dx \right|
\leq \delta
$$
i.e. $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon}$ exists and is finite.